# Firebase user.sendEmailVerification() is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, email, authentication, firebase-authentication

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
     user.sendEmailVerification().then(()=>{console.log("Email Sent")}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
}).catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;    
});
```

Getting error - `user.sendEmailVerification()` is not function.
Can someone help how to send Verification Email in Firebase Authentication?

Comment: To debug you can console.log `user` and see whether the object contains that function

Comment: @mandaputtra figured out the solution . It is `user.user.sendEmailVerification()`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and resolved now.You followed something that is from older versions.The latest library doesn't have the same code u using,please see the latest documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Many thanks, worked for me!